# Node http response returning user password to angular

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, node.js, passport.js

I am using a MEAN stack and trying to set up a basic authentication. The authentication works just fine. Process goes like this:

1. Angular posts user details to "/login".
2. Passport is doing the authentication and redirecting to either "/login/success" or "/login/failure"
3. Both routes return a different simple JSON depending on the result so either:

   res.json({success:true,user:req.session.passport.user});

   or

   return res.json({success:false});

Now, when I `console.log` the result from Angular I get the right JSON. The problem is that in the config object I still see the user details in the config object (username and password) that were posted initially.

I am not sure if this is normal or not but I'd like to return just a simple JSON and no additional data back to the client.

This is what I'm getting in the client. You can see the username and password in the config object.
[image: Image displaying the unwanted data returned with the response.]

Here is a little bit more code:

**Angular HTML Form**

```
            <form action="" ng-submit="submit()">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input ng-model="user.username" type="text" name="user" class="form-control" placeholder="Username">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input ng-model="user.password" type="password" name="pass" class="form-control" placeholder="Password">
                </div>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Login</button>
            </form>
```

**Angular controller:**

```
    $scope.submit = function() {
        $http.post("/login", $scope.user).then(function(data) {
            console.log(data);            
        });
    }
```

**Node routes**

```
app.post('/login', passport.authenticate('local', { 
    successRedirect: '/login/success',
    failureRedirect: '/login/failure'
}));

app.get('/login/success', function(req, res, next){
    console.log("Authentication successful");        
    res.json({success:true,user:req.session.passport.user}); 
});

app.get('/login/failure', function(req, res){
    console.log("Authentication failed");
    res.json({success:false});
});
```

Comment: Can you inspect the request/response to see what the server is actually sending back to the client?  It looks like that might be an artifact from the initial request on the client side?

Comment: There is a screenshot in the post of what the response from the server looks like when consoled from the client side. Is this what you mean?

Comment: No I mean in the Network tab, what does the server respond with?  This is outside the scope of Angular and just what the server responds.  You should see the `POST` request to `/login`, and within that network request, it should show the response data.